# trying to slice array results in "Too many indices for array". Can I pad the array to fix this?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tokenize, recurrent-neural-network

I've seen the multitude of questions about this particular error. I believe my question is different enough to warrant its own post.

**My objective:** I am building an RNN that generates news headlines.  It will predict the next word based on the words that came before it.  This code is from an [example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-word-level-neural-language-model-in-keras/) and I am trying to adapt it to work for my situation.  I am trying to slice the array into an `X` and `y`.

**The issue:**
I understand that the error appears because the array is being indexed as if it were a 2d array, but it is actually a 1d array.  Before converting `sequences` to an array, it is a list of lists, but not all of the nested lists are the same length so numPy converts it to a 1d array.

**My question(s):** Is there a simple or elegant way to pad `sequences` so that all of the lists are the same length? Can I do this using spaces to keep the same meaning in the shorter headlines? Why do I need to change the list of lists to an array at all?  As I said before, this is from an example and I am trying to understand what they did and why.

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Pretreat Data Section
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
# integer encode sequences of words
# create the tokenizer 
t = Tokenizer() 
# fit the tokenizer on the headlines 
t.fit_on_texts(headlines)
sequences = t.texts_to_sequences(headlines)

# vocabulary size
vocab_size = len(t.word_index) + 1

#separate into input and output
sequences = np.array(sequences)
X, y = sequences[:,:-1], sequences[:,-1]     # fix this
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-eb7aab0c3a22> in <module>
     18 #separate into input and output
     19 sequences = np.array(sequences)
---> 20 X, y = sequences[:,:-1], sequences[:,-1]     # fix this
     21 y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=vocab_size)
     22 seq_length = X.shape[1]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas I've edited my question to include the full error message

Comment: How does the tutorial it’s lifted from handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that this tutorial has few parts on one page and every part has own `"Complete Example"`

First `"Complete Example"` reads text from `republic_clean.txt`, clear it and save it in `republic_sequences.txt` - it creates sequences with the same number of words.

Second `"Complete Example"` reads text from `republic_sequences.txt` and use it with

```
sequences = np.array(sequences)
X, y = sequences[:,:-1], sequences[:,-1]
```

Because first part creates sequences with the same number of words so this code works correctly.

It seems you skiped first part. You have to go back to first part to learn how to clear text and how to create correct file which you can use in second part.

---

**EDIT:** if you can't make sequences with the same number of words then you may add spaces to shorter sequences. Code will work but I don't know if it will create better model.

```
sequences = [['a'], ['b','c'], ['d','e','f']]

max_len = max(map(len, sequences))

sequences = [x + [""]*(max_len-len(x)) for x in sequences]

print(sequences)
```

Result

```
[['a', '', ''], ['b', 'c', ''], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Comment: I don't have my entire file in my question.  My trouble I think comes from the data I am using as it is different from the data in the tutorial.  In the tutorial he creates sequences from The Republic, which because its a book, naturally flows and he can start one sequence after the other ends and keep them all the same length.  My data is a million different news headlines which are unrelated and different lengths and I am not sure how to create sequences that are the same length because I do not think that his method makes sense for this application. @furas

Comment: code will not work if you will have sentences with different number of words. If you can't cut headers then find the longest sentence and use its size to append spaces to other sequences - ie. `['a'] + ['']*2` - code will works but I'm not sure if spaces will make better model.

Comment: @JacobMyer A question should include the *shortest possible example data that actually reproduces the problem*, as given in [mre] guidelines.

Comment: I added example how to add spaces to sequences to make all the same length.

Comment: That is what I thought.  I don't know if my question was clear or not but what I was really asking about is how to solve the different lengths issue.  I tried using `maxLen = len(max(sequences, key=len))` and
`sequences = [(seq + '' * (maxLen - len(seq)) for seq in sequences)]` before converting `sequences = np.array(sequences)` and adding the `char_level=True` argument  to the tokenizer function.  This still resulted in the same error as before however.  I will try what you posted now.

Comment: now I checked that sequences have number, not words. Tokenizer change words in number - but I don't know if it will works correctly if you add number `0` because it can be assigned to word. Using `vocab_size+1` would be better. Before Tokenizer every line is one string with words, not list of words - so adding spaces would not work because Tokenizer will remove them. It would have to be some word.

Comment: @furas I could be wrong but I believe that is correct unless I specify `char_level=True`, in which case it considers a space as a character.  I made the changes you suggested and that argument I just mentioned, and I was able to get the code to run past the slicing line (line 20 above) but I get another error on line 21: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`  I don't know if this is related or if it warrants its own post

Comment: It is related to spaces - original `sequences` have only numbers, not words, and rest of code works only with numbers. If you add space to `sequences` then it tries to convert space to number and `int("")` gives error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''. I tried to add number `vocab_size` instead of space but then you have to `vocab_size+1` in line `y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=vocab_size+1)`. And rest should work. I have old computer and Keras can't work - probably it needs graphics card which works with `CUDA`.

Comment: @furas Thanks for your help, I was able to solve this last issue in another way but I couldn't have gotten this far without your tips above.  You are right it is because adding `" "` to the sequences is adding a string onto a list of numbers.  How I solved it was to do the list comprehension adding spaces to `headlines` instead of `sequences` because headlines comes before the tokenizer, where it is converted to numbers.